# On dragging Tab out(used Dragablz) in which flyleaf mediaplayer is playing making the player to stuck on the last window itself

Tags: c#, wpf, flyleaf

I'm developing a program in which you can view several different video and image streams, in which I'm swapping our old video player with Flyleaf.

The simplified basic structure of the program goes:

- Window
- Tabs
  Tabs are drag and droppable, and I have no issue doing so within the same window. But when I drag and drop a tab onto the other window, the tab changes windows, but the FlyleafHosts are still drawn on top of the first window, Surface and Overlay windows are still children of the main window. This causes the whole program to be out of sync. Drag'n'Drop works properly with all other SlotElements, which are native WPF elements.

Is there a method I should call to notify the FlyleafHosts to update their Owner property?
I tried calling Deattach() followed by Attach(), but that didn't work.